# Removing substring from shell output

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to get the version of nginx on my server using `sed`

My attempt

```
nginx -v  | sed -e "s|nginx version: nginx/||"
```

Output

```
nginx version: nginx/1.9.12
```

**Expected output**

```
1.9.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx prints version to stderr, so you need to redirect the output:

```
nginx -v 2>&1 | sed -e "s|nginx version: nginx/||"
#        ^ redirect stderr to stdout
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the Sample of output

```
nginx version: nginx/1.2.3
built by gcc 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --without-http_autoindex_module --without-http_userid_module --without-http_auth_basic_module --without-http_fastcgi_module --without-http_empty_gif_module --with-poll_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --with-http_geoip_module
```

Comment: There is a difference between `nginx -v`and `nginx -V`